# C Programming Printing array of chars of a file

Tags: c, file-io, char

I am making a program that will take a text file (FORMAT: 9-Digit ID, First name, Last name, Grades) such as..

```
123123123 Joe Brown 75 80 90 70 
321321321 William Smith 100 90 95 80
312312312 Rob Black 70 80 85 95
```

and as for output display only the ID #, followed by the average of the grades and a letter grade that corresponds with their average. I have been struggling to find what is wrong with my code. For some reason the last character in each of the ID's is a "@" symbol, and I cannot figure out why.

Output:

```
12312312@ 79 C
32132132@ 91 A
31231231@ 83 B
```

Here is my file, excuse my code I just started:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main (){
 //characters we need
 char c;
 char id[10];
 char fname[20];
 char lname[20];
 char num[4];
 int grades[20];
 //counters
 int i = 0;
 int j = 0;
 int k = 0;
 int m = 0;
 int p = 0;
 int numNums = 0;
 //for whole file
 while(1) {//filewhile
  //for each line
  while(1) {//linewhile
   i = 0;
   j = 0;
   k = 0;
   m = 0;
   numNums = 0;
   //reads id
   while((c=getchar()) != ' ' && c!=10 && c!=EOF) id[i++]=c;
   //reads fname
   while((c=getchar()) != ' ' && c!=10 && c!=EOF) fname[j++]=c;
   //reads lname
   while((c=getchar()) != ' ' && c!=10 && c!=EOF) lname[k++]=c;
   //reads each grade
    while(1){//numwhile
     p=0;
     while((c=getchar()) != ' ' && c != 10 && c != EOF) {
      num[p++]=c;
     }
     //terminates num array
     num[p]=0;
     //converts num into ints and puts in grades array
     grades[m++]=atoi(num);
     numNums++;
     if(c==10 || c == EOF) break;
    }//numwhile
   //stuff to average the persons grade
   int n = 0;
   int total=0;
   for(n=0; n<numNums; n++){
   total += grades[n];
   }
   int average = total / numNums;
   if(average>=90){printf("%10s %d A", id, average); printf("\n");}
   else if(average>=80){printf("%10s %d B", id, average); printf("\n");}
   else if(average>=70){printf("%10s %d C", id, average); printf("\n");}
   else if(average>=60){printf("%10s %d D", id, average); printf("\n");}
   break;
  }//linewhile
  if(c==EOF) break;
 }//filewhile
}//main
```

Comment: You need to null-terminate your strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the null character at the end of each id

for example:

```
id[9] = '\0';
```

Comment: I added this line of code in and now my output is indented by 1 space. It is printing a space at the beginning of each line, any idea why this may be?

Comment: Look like it because you specified you wanted to print 10 characters the id is getting padded with spaces to get to 10 characters. When you print strings you do not need to specify how many characters you need to print....you just print it.
change the formatting line to something like 

'printf("%s %d D\n", id, average);' and remove the additional 'printf("\n");'

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with using a length specifier for the strings. In this case you want it to be left aligned instead of the default of right aligned, so use printf("%-10s").  But please follow hebbo's advice for *all* your strings. Also if you want 10 characters of user input, you should allocate 11 characters to store your string. The extra character is needed to store the null character.